# Is it possible to uninstall default Windows 10 apps with Intune? If so, how?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-intune

Through Intune, is it possible to uninstall default Windows 10 apps; like Pandora, X-box and Candy Crush? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall default apps from Windows 10 with Intune.

1. Go to the **Intune portal and sign** in with your credentials.
2. Click on **Apps** and then **Windows**.
3. Click **Add** and select "Microsoft Store app (new)".
4. Search for the app you want to uninstall.
5. Click on **Assignments**.
6. Click on **Add Group**.
7. Select **Uninstall** under Assignment type.
8. Click on **Included Groups** and select the group of devices you want to
   uninstall the app from.
9. Select **Yes** behind Uninstall this app for all users.
10. Click **OK** twice and click Save.

Comment: I forgot this question was out here. And now see that the answers are all in need of updating, since Microsoft Intune's move to using WinGet. Be the first to explain how to use the New Store for uninstalling and I'll switch the accepted answer.

Comment: @NathanHartley  Pacific P. Regmi's instructions explain the instructions using the new store.

Comment: So, it does. Step 3 should say Add the app type "Microsoft Store app (new)".

Answer (score 4):

I found this blog post. It worked for me to uninstall the Eclipse Manager from my Windows 10 device. 
- Add the app you want to uninstall to your Business Store
- Sync your store with Intune
- Configure the app in your Intune to uninstall, all devices or users, or based on a group.

https://www.data3.com/knowledge-centre/blog/uninstall-unwanted-windows-10-applications-using-intune/